# What are pop-rivet aluminium security bars vulnerable to?

Tags: windows, security

Our landlord is replacing our windows. They've proposed moving from:

- wooden frame
- steel security bars
- screwed into frame

to:

- metal frame
- aluminium security bars
- pop rivets

Assume we leave our windows open and a burglar attempts to break in (I appreciate that any bars are themselves a deterrent). Will a burglar have any easier time with the new windows than the old windows? Put another way, what attacks are pop-rivet aluminium security bars vulnerable to that screwed-in steel bars aren't?

Comment: amused that my first diy question is about windows security

Comment: As a practical matter, no difference.  If someone went to the window intent on cutting through the bars, they could do it faster.  But seeing the window with bars, they aren't likely to use that as an entry point.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have this (false?) impression that steel bars are really difficult to get through, while aluminium bars can be easily forced with a crowbar - not true?

Comment: How easy it is depends on the type/style of bars and the leverage available.  So some aluminum bars might be relatively easy.  However, people looking to break in look for easy targets.  Windows with any kind of bars will discourage people from trying to use that window unless they have specifically targeted your house and don't see a faster, easier access point.  They would have to be seriously casing your house to get close enough and spend time determining what the bars are made of.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for the helpful comments, I have refined the question and added how the bars are attached

Comment: If someone targets your specific house, and cases it looking for vulnerable access points, and discovers on close inspection that the window bars are held on with pop rivets, and has a tool like a crowbar or returns another time with a crowbar, and isn't concerned about making some noise, then yes, it would probably be easier to remove those bars than removing iron bars screwed into wood framing (although that wouldn't be too hard, either, unless it was seriously screwed in with many really big and long screws).

Comment: BTW, security bars on windows can also interfere with you getting out in the event of an emergency, or fire or emergency crews from using those windows.  So the security value cuts both ways.

Comment: I thought local codes generally required each room to have one fire escape route. So at least one widow would have to allow ready escape from inside. Don't some designs of window bars have a release mechanism operable from inside?

Answer (score 2):

> **what attacks are aluminium security bars vulnerable to that steel bars aren't?**

- Aluminium is a lot softer than steel and is quicker to cut through using a hacksaw.
- There are hardened grades of steel that considerably increase its resistance to cutting compared to "plain" steel.
- The same diameter bar in aluminium is much less strong than steel and so more vulnerable to bending, stretching and shearing.
- Aluminium is a fairly reactive metal but your security bars are probably not going to be attacked chemically by a would-be intruder.